# List splice Function

Tags: java, linked-list

I need to write a function that splices two list objects. For example

`public static List splice(List l1, List l2) // takes two lists and interleaves them`

The output for example should be

`splice([1,2,3],[a,b,c])`

should give the list 
`[1,a,2,b,3,c]` If the two lists are of unequal length, then the function should interleave as much as possible, then append the remainder of the longer list. For example,

`splice([1,2],[a,b,c,d])` should give `[1,a,2,b,c,d]`

How would this be achieved?

Comment: this is usually achieved by the user, you, writing a function that does this instead of asking for someone to write it for you

Answer (score 0):

You can use iterators to move over each list in turn:

```
static <T> List<T> splice(List<T> one, List<T> two) {
    Iterator<T> oneIter = one.iterator();
    Iterator<T> twoIter = two.iterator();
    List<T> result = new ArrayList<T>();

    while (oneIter.hasNext() || twoIter.hasNext()) {
        if (oneIter.hasNext()) {
            result.add(oneIter.next());
        }
        if (twoIter.hasNext()) {
            result.add(twoIter.next());
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

You can test this like so:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(splice(
        Arrays.asList("one", "two", "three"),
        Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3)
    ));
}
```

This prints:

```
[one, 1, two, 2, three, 3]
```